# AsyncTask does not run on next Activity invocation

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my splash screen Activity I run some lengthy initializations. So I create a background Async Task and execute it to do the heavy lifting. The main Activity (UI) thread then displays the splash screen image and returns from the onCreate() method, which causes the screen to be updated. When the Asynch Task completes it invokes a method on the splash screen activity that invokes the main activity and terminates itself.

This works wonderfully the first time the app is run. If I terminate the application and then restart it, a brand new Async Task is created, and when the execute method is called the onPreExecute() method is called, but the doInBackground() method is never called on this second run.

If I use task manager to forcibly kill the application then it works properly. The issue arises when the application has completed (device home screen shown) but has yet to be reclaimed by the OS.

I create a brand new Async Task object and check that it is not cancelled prior to calling the execute() method. Its as if the Async Task remembers about the previous instance and fails to start the new Async Task because it thinks that its already executed once.

Why is the brand new Async Task not calling the doInBackground() method when execute is called?

Code of Async Task:

```
public class AsynchTaskInitializeApplication extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

    private ActivitySplashScreen theActivity;

    public AsynchTaskInitializeApplication() {
            Log.d("App", "AsynchTaskInitializeApplication constructor called\n");
    }

    public void setTheActivity(ActivitySplashScreen theActivity) {
            Log.d("App", "AsynchTaskInitializeApplication::setTheActivity() called\n");
            this.theActivity = theActivity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            boolean result = false;

            Log.d("App", "AsynchTaskInitializeApplication::doInBackground() called\n");

            try {
                    // Initialization code goes here
                    result = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Something went wrong - we failed.
                    // Return false result.
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.d("App", "AsynchTaskInitializeApplication::onPreExecute() called\n");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (this.theActivity != null) {
                    this.theActivity.initializationComplete(result);
            }
    }
}
```

Creation / invocation code:

```
    // Start the asynchronous task that starts the data store and does
    // any other heavy hitting initialization.
    this.mBackgroundInitialization = null;
    this.mBackgroundInitialization = new AsynchTaskInitializeApplication();
    this.mBackgroundInitialization.setTheActivity(this);
    Log.d("App", "ActivitySplashScreen::onCreate() start the background initialization\n");
    if (this.mBackgroundInitialization.isCancelled()) {
            Log.d("App", "ActivitySplashScreen::onCreate() background initialization task already cancelled\n");
    }       
    this.mBackgroundInitialization.execute();
    Log.d("App", "ActivitySplashScreen::onCreate() background initialization should have started\n");
```

The code that is called when the background task completes:

```
    public void initializationComplete(boolean readyToGo) {
    Log.d("App", "Initialization is complete " + readyToGo + "\n");
    // Attempt to forcibly stop the background task.
    // A second attempt to run the app does not cause it to execute. 
    if (!this.mBackgroundInitialization.isCancelled()) {
            this.mBackgroundInitialization.cancel(true);
    }
    this.mBackgroundInitialization = null;

    // Display the home screen
    Intent homeScreenIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityHomeScreen.class);
    try {   
           startActivity(homeScreenIntent);

           // And quit this activity so that when the home screen activity
           // finishes then the application finishes
           this.finish();
    } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            errorMessage = "Cannot find activity for intent: " + homeScreenIntent.toString();
    } catch(Exception e) {
            errorMessage = "Unknown exception when launching intent: " + homeScreenIntent.toString();
    }
    Log.e("App", errorMessage);
    this.finish();
    }
```

The logcat output of the successful first run case, notice the doInBackground() method announces itself, and the initialization completes:

```
01-22 23:59:30.133 10195 10195 D App: AsynchTaskInitializeApplication constructor called
01-22 23:59:30.133 10195 10195 D App: AsynchTaskInitializeApplication::setTheActivity() called
01-22 23:59:30.133 10195 10195 D App: ActivitySplashScreen::onCreate() start the background initialization
01-22 23:59:30.133 10195 10195 D App: AsynchTaskInitializeApplication::onPreExecute() called
01-22 23:59:30.133 10195 10195 D App: ActivitySplashScreen::onCreate() background initialization should have started
01-22 23:59:30.157 10195 10207 D App: AsynchTaskInitializeApplication::doInBackground() called
01-22 23:59:30.477 10195 10195 D App: Initialization is complete true
```

The logcat output of the second run where the doInBackground() does not run:

```
01-23 00:02:45.868 10195 10195 D App: AsynchTaskInitializeApplication constructor called
01-23 00:02:45.868 10195 10195 D App: AsynchTaskInitializeApplication::setTheActivity() called
01-23 00:02:45.868 10195 10195 D App: ActivitySplashScreen::onCreate() start the background initialization
01-23 00:02:45.868 10195 10195 D App: AsynchTaskInitializeApplication::onPreExecute() called
01-23 00:02:45.868 10195 10195 D App: ActivitySplashScreen::onCreate() background initialization should have started
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your answer lies in the use of more than just the onCreate() method. If you are familiar with the Activity Lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

You know that when your app goes to different states, you can call different methods to handle the new state. In this case you want to make sure that just like when you run the app for the first time, the AsyncTask that seems to be causing issues has been destroyed. Use:

```
    myAsyncTask.cancel();
```

Where proper for your app to attempt to end the task.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Flynn added this comment before I added the sample code. There is an explicit cancel in the code path that is causing me problems. There is one in the onPause() as well in case that happens before the app is suspended prior to the initialization completes.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to log the asynctask's status.

Comment: Good idea. Did not know you could get that (I must read the docs, I must read the docs). I'll see what it says.

Comment: you can use getStatus() that method returns AsyncTask.Status enumeration.